# Are frames generated by a single Nvidia graphics card for multiple displays synchronized?

Tags: opengl, rendering, nvidia

I have an opengl application window that stretches across two displays connected to the same Nvidia graphics card. I need some kind of technical proof that the displays will show the frames in synchronized order.

Lets say I render a sequence of frames. Can I be sure that the frames are always put out in synchronized order:

```
Display 1      Display 2
1              1
2              2
3              3
...
```

Or is it possible that cases like this occur:

```
4              5
6              7
...
```

If not, is there a technical feature that prevents unsynchronized output? My naive guess would be that the graphics card has only one clock signal so frames cannot be unsynchronized, but I would like to have a more substantial answer.

If there is a technical feature, which type of graphics cards would it require (Geforce, Quadro)?

Would it be possible that the graphics library matters in this respect? Or is it solely a hardware-related topic?

PS:
I DO NOT mean synchronized frames from multiple graphics cards or render clients using Nvidia Sync technology. I mostly just found information about that, hence my question.

Comment: Arguably the frames might differ by less than a complete frame.

Comment: Some quadro cards can by synced with a quadro sync card. Then I would expect the output of a single Quadro cards to be synced for sure.

Comment: On nvidia, it is typically _nvidia mosaic_ on the quadro series, AMD has _eyefinity_.